# How to navigate to a screen from another screen inscribed in a 3 level navigator

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am a newbie to react native. I am using Login and Home screens in a stack navigator in which home screen consist a tab navigator with each tab having 2 or 3 screens; so i added a stack navigator inside that tab navigator (3 Level navigator).

app.js

```
export const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
  login: { screen: LoginPage },
  homepage: { screen : HomePage },
});
```

home.js

```
export const MyApp = TabNavigator({

  Asset: {
    screen: AssetScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
          tabBarLabel: 'Asset',
          tabBarIcon:  (
                <Image source={require('../logos/tab_assets.png')}
                       style={[styles.icon, {color: '#ffffff'}]}
                />
          )
    },
  },
  Sensors: {
    screen: sensorsStack,
    navigationOptions: {
          tabBarLabel: 'Sensor',
          tabBarIcon:  (
                <Image source={require('../logos/tab_sensor.png')}
                       style={[styles.icon, {color: '#ffffff'}]}
                />
          )
    },
  },
   Settings: {
        screen: settingStack,
        navigationOptions: {
              tabBarLabel: 'Settings',
              tabBarIcon:  (
                    <Image source={require('../logos/tab_settings.png')}
                           style={[styles.icon, {color: '#ffffff'}]}
                    />
              )
        },
   },
}
```

With again stack navigator for sensors and settings tab.

```
export const sensorsStack = StackNavigator({
  sensors : { screen: SensorScreen },
  sensorDetails : { screen: SensorDetails }

});
export const settingStack = StackNavigator({
  settings: { screen: SettingsScreen },
  about : { screen: About },
  environment : { screen: Environment }
});
```

I have signout button in settingsScreen, by clicking on it i want to navigate the screen to login which is in app.js stack.

I have tried using nagivation.back() in settingsScreen but it is going back to homepage not login. Is there any way i can achieve this? or any other way to provide login access to my app.

Comment: You can navigate to a certain route as well by using the Navigate action of Navigation actions. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-actions

Comment: this.props.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.back('home')); but still didnt work.
I have used navigation.reset while navigating from login to home.
Is this the issues for going back to login screen from signout screen.


`const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
              index: 0,
              actions: [
                  NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'homepage' ,params: { assetID:data, assetPassword: assetPassword, authToken: token, sensorData: this.state.sensorData }})

              ],
          });
          this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);`